# Why is my python regular expression finding matches, but only giving empty values?

Tags: python

I have a working regular expression that is used to pull 'cid' image references out of the body of an email. I have tested this regex successfully with .NET and regex101.com. It is successful in both instances. When I try in Python, I get the expected number of matches, but they are all empty strings. Code is below.

```
x = re.findall(r"\*?cid\:(.*?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-.@]+.*?", msg.body)
for s in x:
    print(len(s))
```

Output:

The top five lines are the expected matches. The bottom lines are the output from the code above.

[image: command line output]

Here it is working on regex101.com

[image: regex101.com output]

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you add the content of `msg.body`?

Comment: `findall` is returning the result of your capture group `(.*?)` which is empty, there are indeed regex matches for the full expression, you just have to adjust your capture group. From your examples I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to capture within the matched strings

Comment: You probably need to use a non-capturing group. Then `re.findall()` returns the entire match, not just the group.

Comment: Or just don't put `.*?` in a group at all. there doesn't seem to be a point to it. Since it's a non-greedy quantifier, it's matching the empty string before the next `[a-zA-Z0-9\-.@]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

findall() is capturing you inner regex group in parenthesis. To avoid this, include ?: in you regex as:

```
x = re.findall(r"\*?cid\:(?:.*?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-.@]+.*?", x, flags=0)
```